# Winforms Circular Checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms

So here is my next creation, a circular checkbox. This is my third custom control, so I'm still learning, but have the basics just about down. Tips and suggestions are most appreciated:

```
class CircularCheckbox : Control
{
    private Color borderColor;
    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return borderColor; }
        set { borderColor = value; }
    }

    private Color background;
    public Color Background
    {
        get { return background; }
        set { background = value; }
    }

    private Color tickColor;
    public Color TickColor
    {
        get { return tickColor; }
        set { tickColor = value; }
    }

    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set { isChecked = value; }
    }

    public CircularCheckbox(bool IsChecked)
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        this.IsChecked = IsChecked;
        Background = Color.White;
        BorderColor = Color.Black;
        TickColor = Color.Green;
    }

    public CircularCheckbox()
        : this(false)
    { }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        Rectangle rc = this.ClientRectangle;
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
        Font f = new Font("Arial", (float)rc.Height * 0.5f, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Background), rc.Left + 1.5f, rc.Top + 1.5f, rc.Width - 4.0f, rc.Height - 4.0f);
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(BorderColor), 3.0f), rc.Left + 1.5f, rc.Top + 1.5f, rc.Width - 4.0f, rc.Height - 4.0f);

        if (IsChecked)
            g.DrawString("\u2713", f, new SolidBrush(tickColor) , rc, sf);

    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);

        IsChecked = IsChecked ? false : true;

        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice if you added a screenshot of your creation + how it looks in all of its states, i.e. explain the code without the need to read code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Other people have mentioned that you should use auto-properties, but they're missing another point about custom controls. When someone changes a property of your custom control which should result in a change in how your control is drawn, you need to `Invalidate` your control.

```
private bool isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return isChecked; }
    set
    {
        if (value == isChecked) return;
        isChecked = value;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

The `if` check ensure we're not needlessly invalidating the control when there won't be an actual change in the painting logic. Again, this should be done for any property whose value being changed means the drawing needs to be done - which in this case is all of your properties.

You should also be properly disposing of the drawing objects you're creating. The best way to do this is to create the objects in a `using` block. Note that you can pass a color directly to the `Pen` constructor instead of passing a `Brush` object (which would have to be disposed of properly if you went that route).

```
using (var backgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(Background))
using (var borderPen = new Pen(BorderColor, 3.0f))
{
    g.FillEllipse(backgroundBrush, rc.Left + 1.5f, rc.Top + 1.5f, rc.Width - 4.0f, rc.Height - 4.0f);
    g.DrawEllipse(borderPen, rc.Left + 1.5f, rc.Top + 1.5f, rc.Width - 4.0f, rc.Height - 4.0f);
}
```

Your `Font` and `StringFormat` instances should also be getting disposed of properly.

Another thing to keep in mind is that it is possible for other code to add a `Paint` event handler which will be run after you perform your painting. You're changing the `SmoothingMode` of your graphics object and not restoring it before you complete your painting. I'd recommend restoring the `Graphics` back to its original state before you complete.

```
// At the beginning of your drawing
var originalGraphicsState = e.Graphics.Save();
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

/// .. draw some stuff ..

// At the end of your drawing
e.Graphics.Restore(originalGraphicsState);
```

Comment: +1 good points especially `using`. For the properties I agree but not with the `IsChecked` because it is handled by `override void OnClick()`. But maybe it would be better to put the call to `Invalidate()` inside each property setter

Comment: I wrote this comment without looking at the code ;-) corrected comment.

Comment: My point still stands though, if some outside code calls `myCustomCheckBox.IsChecked = true` it will set the property but not repaint the graphics. If you want to get rid of the `Invalidate` in the `IsChecked` public setter you need to make the property setter private - or maybe protected with a good comment explaining that the caller must `Invalidate` the control after setting the value.

Comment: If you see this from the point as a public avaiable assembly, then you are right, but then the class should be public, shouldn' it.

Comment: Even if it is internal (which this class currently is defaulting to), it means it can be changed by other code within your own assembly. When building a `Form` within the same assembly, you can place a `CircularCheckbox` in the form and then set the value from within your custom `Form`. Without invalidating in the property setter, all of the sudden your `Form` needs to know to call `Invalidate` after setting the property. It is the responsibility of the `CircularCheckbox` to know when it needs to redraw itself, which is the moment the `IsChecked` property is changed.

Comment: Right, but then it should use property changed event.

Answer (score 12):

- you should use auto properties where you don't need any validation. So all of your properties should use them like instead of

  > ```
  > private bool isChecked;
  > public bool IsChecked
  > {
  >     get { return isChecked; }
  >     set { isChecked = value; }
  > }
  > ```

  you would use

  ```
  public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
  ```
- this example of really unnecessary tenary expression

  > ```
  > IsChecked = IsChecked ? false : true;
  > ```

  should be replaced by

  ```
  IsChecked = !IsChecked;
  ```
- using braces `{}` for single `if` statement also would make your code less errorprone
- you should extract your **magic numbers** into some meaningful aka good named constants ( `3.0f` , `1.5f` etc)
- you should extract `"\u2713"` to some meaningful constant
- you should extract `new SolidBrush(tickColor)` to a field, as the brush itself won't change.

Answer (score 9):

In general your code is good, like the fact that you implemented constructor overloading, but there's always room for improvements:

- **Backfield-properties vs. Auto-implemented properties:**

  You are not doing anything internally with your backing fields, like validation of `value` for example. So there's no use in implementing properties this way. Use **[auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)** instead. Following property:

  ```
  private Color borderColor;
  public Color BorderColor
  {
      get { return borderColor; }
      set { borderColor = value; }
  }
  ```

  would become:

  ```
  public Color BorderColor { get; set; }
  ```

  This also goes for the other properties.
- **Naming:**

  The names of your private fields for the properties have correct names, try to continue doing this for all names in your code. Don't use variable names like `rc`, `g` and `sf`, they don't mean anything. Use `rectangle`, `graphics` and `stringFormat`/`format` instead.

  In the constructor with the parameter, the name is capitalized. Parameter names use `camelCase` and not `PascalCase`, Make it `isChecked`. (**[More reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx)**)
- **Nitpicking:**

  Although following line is not incorrect, it can be simplified.

  ```
  IsChecked = IsChecked ? false : true;
  ```

  would become:

  ```
  IsChecked = !IsChecked;
  ```

Comment: You wear a nice hat ;-)